# How to remove %20%20 from url in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am getting problem in url.%20%20 is adding in url.I have tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method.

But still it shows %20%20 in url.

Here is code that i am using:

```
redirectUrl += "&return=" & Server.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL") & "?item_name=" + Server.UrlEncode(ItemDescription.ToString()) + "&amount=" + Server.UrlEncode(Amount.ToString()) + "&quantity=" + Server.UrlEncode(qty.ToString()))
```

Here is return url in browser:

```
http://localhost:53725/Project/SuccessPayment.aspx%20%20?item_name=%2b%27ULTRA%2bANTI-STATIC%2bWRIST%2bSTRAP%27&amount=9%2e99&quantity=1
```

If i will able to remove %20%20 before querystring variable(?).Then url will work for me.

Please suggest me how i can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%20` is a space character. So you need to trim it away:

```
redirectUrl = Server.UrlDecode(redirectUrl).Trim() + "&return=" & Server.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL") & "?item_name=" + Server.UrlEncode(ItemDescription.ToString()) + "&amount=" + Server.UrlEncode(Amount.ToString()) + "&quantity=" + Server.UrlEncode(qty.ToString()))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `Trim` be round the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL")` in your answer since in the question the `%20%20` is before `?item_name`?

Comment: Now you say it,,, yes it should.